# How to filter/aggregate and re-merge with original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, aggregate

I'm trying to get the max date (and associated Course) of each Horse from a "history" dataframe (DFH) and then I want to use the max date to populate the original dataframe (DF1) with the max date and associated Course for each Horse.

A) Initially I merge DF1 with a larger base data file to get DFH (i.e. I add every HxCourse and HxDate to DF1 for each Horse in DF1)
B) Next, I do an aggregate of DFH to get the max HxDate for each Horse (this is the last date the horse ran).  I also need the HxCourse. However, this is where I get stuck.  I can't find a way to get the HxCourse.
C) I then need to add the HxDate and HxCourse to DF1 to give me the output.

My code has some errors:
"Exception has occurred: TypeError Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'NoneType'> was passed"
"merge.py:648: UserWarning"
"generic.py:4153: PerformanceWarning"

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

OUTPUT: What I need:

```
    Course  Date    Time    Horse   HxCourse    HxDate
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:00   CAPRICORN PRINCE    Brighton    2021-09-13 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Chelmsford City 2021-12-02 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Southwell   2021-12-10 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Lingfield   2021-12-31 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Southwell   2021-12-16 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Southwell   2021-12-29 00:00:00
```

:
DF1 - Original Dataframe:

```
    Course  Date    Time    Horse
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:00   CAPRICORN PRINCE
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT
```

DFH - History Dataframe (this is DF1 merged with a large database of all horse races)

```
Course  Date    Time    Horse   HxCourse    HxDate
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:00   CAPRICORN PRINCE    Brighton    2021-09-13 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:00   CAPRICORN PRINCE    Lingfield   2021-08-25 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:00   CAPRICORN PRINCE    Kempton 2021-08-11 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:00   CAPRICORN PRINCE    Wolverhampton   2021-04-20 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Chelmsford City 2021-12-02 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Chelmsford City 2021-11-11 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Newcastle   2021-11-05 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Bath    2021-06-30 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Lingfield   2021-06-14 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Wolverhampton   2021-06-08 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Chelmsford City 2021-05-20 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Lingfield   2021-05-08 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Pontefract  2021-04-19 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   CLIPSHAM TIGER  Wolverhampton   2021-04-05 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Southwell   2021-12-10 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Chelmsford City 2021-11-26 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Leicester   2021-10-05 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Leicester   2021-09-20 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Nottingham  2021-08-13 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Nottingham  2021-07-16 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 16:55   FINERY  Yarmouth    2021-07-07 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Lingfield   2021-12-31 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Kempton 2021-12-15 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Chelmsford City 2021-11-22 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Kempton 2021-11-12 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Wolverhampton   2021-10-18 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Pontefract  2021-10-04 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Thirsk  2021-09-04 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Newmarket   2021-07-30 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Doncaster   2021-07-08 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Pontefract  2021-05-28 00:00:00
Southwell   2022-03-02 00:00:00 13:00   FOLLOW YOUR HEART   Wolverhampton   2021-03-12 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Southwell   2021-12-16 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Wolverhampton   2021-11-27 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Wolverhampton   2021-11-01 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Wolverhampton   2021-10-18 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Wolverhampton   2021-06-08 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 19:00   HIGHEST AMBITION    Nottingham  2021-05-18 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Southwell   2021-12-29 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Chelmsford City 2021-10-09 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Chelmsford City 2021-09-25 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Chelmsford City 2021-09-12 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Chelmsford City 2021-08-03 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Chelmsford City 2021-07-20 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  York    2021-06-11 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Kempton 2021-03-27 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Lingfield   2021-03-19 00:00:00
Chelmsford  2022-03-02 00:00:00 18:00   NIGEL NOTT  Chelmsford City 2021-03-13 00:00:00
```

:

```
import pandas as pd



path = (r"C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\PythonSand\PY_Scripts\CleanModules\Racecards")
hist_file = r"\Stk_hrshist.xlsx"
racecard = r"\Stk_racecard.xlsx"

racecard_path = path + hist_file
df_hist = pd.read_excel(racecard_path, index_col=None) #"history" dataframe (DFH) 

racecard_path = path + racecard
df_racecard = pd.read_excel(racecard_path, index_col=None) #original dataframe (DF1) 

df_hst = df_hist[["Horse","HxDate"]].copy()
df_hst_grp = df_hst.groupby(["Horse"], as_index=False).agg({"HxDate":["max"]})
df_hst_grp = pd.DataFrame(df_hst_grp)

df1 = pd.merge(df_racecard, df_hst_grp, how='outer', left_on=["Horse"], right_on = ["Horse"])
df1 = df1.rename({"('HxDate', 'max')": "lastdate"}, axis='columns', inplace =True) # Renaming column A with 'new_a' and B with 'new_b'

df2 = pd.merge(df1, hist_file, how='outer', left_on=["Horse","Date","Time","lastdate"], right_on = ["Horse","Date","Time","HxDate"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an intermediate solution as I still haven't figured out how to merge with the aggregate dataframe.
How to find the max date (and associated Course) of each Horse from a "history" dataframe (DFH).
I discovered that getting unique values returns the first duplicate.  So, by sorting the data on Horse and HxDate I can then get the first unique rows.  This dataframe can then be merged with DF1 (the Original Dataframe).

```
racecard_path = path + hist_file
df_hist = pd.read_excel(racecard_path, index_col=None) #"history" dataframe (DFH) 

racecard_path = path + racecard
df_racecard = pd.read_excel(racecard_path, index_col=None) #original dataframe (DF1) 

df_last_date = df_hist[["Horse","HxCourse","HxDate"]].copy()
df_last_date.sort_values(by = ["Horse","HxDate"], ascending = [True, False], na_position = 'first')
df_last_date = df_last_date.drop_duplicates(subset=['Horse'])

df_rc_m_ld = pd.merge(df_racecard, df_last_date, how='left', left_on=["Horse"], right_on = ["Horse"])
```